# Malware/Adware on my wordpress blog--want to reinstall

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

My Wordpress site has some strange adware. Sometimes it redirects to www.usgrants.org , and at one point there was some random text at the bottom of each page that looked like search engine keywords, but that text seemed to have disappeared for now.

So instead, I've decided to back up my blog, and just start fresh with my database, and just reinstall the plugins that I really need.

The question is, how can I do this without losing my content?

I am guessing it is just as easy as exporting my SQL database, deleting everything, reinstalling WP, and then importing it, but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way.

I'm also looking into Duplicator, but I don't know if that would also migrate the problematic add-ons (I don't even know what the cause of it is).

I'd really love to keep my Thesis theme as well, but I'm not sure if my custom code is causing the problem.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost if you are still able to get into the admin area of your site, I would install WordFence (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/), do a complete scan of your site, and make the recommended fixes. Additionally, if you can spring for it, I would get the premium version as it will scan all files on the server, not just in the wordpress install. (I think it's like $40 per year per domain & gets cheaper the more you add.) This option may rescue your current site without the need to start fresh.

That said, if you have malware in your site, it's very difficult to know for sure that it's fixed for good. Depending upon how it's written, it can lie dormant for a while and come back when you least expect it so starting over may be the best idea. Regardless, I would use WordFence to scan first before you start fresh since it will also scan your database to see if anything ended up in one of your tables there. The free version will do that too.

Then you can either export and save your database from MYSQL or you can also use the wordpress export / import tool to manage the transfer of your content. Its a pretty simple process.

To export your site data using the included WP Export tool.
1. Login to the backend admin
2. Navigate to tools
3. Click on 'Export'
4. Select the All Content option and then press the 'Download Export File' button.
5. This will download an XML file that you can import on your new instance of WP.

To import your site data using the WP Import tool.
1. Login to the backend admin
2. Navigate to tools and click import
3. Select 'WordPress' from the list
4. Install the importer
5. Click Activate and Run Plugin
6. Choose the XML file you exported and then select Upload File and Import.

Hope this helps!